# Unable custom sorting my ag-grid using comparator

Tags: typescript, aurelia, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid (version 16) inside my Aurelia app. All columns are sortable. One of these columns needs custom sorting. As explained in the ag-grid documentation this is possible:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#custom-sorting

They provide an example for javascript by using a **comparator**. It seems really simple at first.

When I try to use a comparator inside my own code (but this time using TypeScript), this code is just never reached (debugger instruction never called).

Below is my code:

```
constructor(...) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },
      ...
      {
        headerName: "Indice",
        field: "indice",
        width: 90,
        sort: 'desc',
        comparator: (valueA, valueB) => this.indiceComparator(valueA, valueB);
      }
 }
 private indiceComparator(valueA, valueB) {
    debugger;
    // Never reached !
    return 0;
}

// When initializing my grid options
this.gridOptions.enableServerSideFilter = true;
this.gridOptions.enableFilter = true;
this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite';
```

I don't know where is the problem but I am using TypeScript and the example provided on the ag-grid website is using JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried comparator: this.indiceComparator().bind(this)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: try `comparator: (valueA, valueB) => console.log(valueA, valueB);` do you see them in the log?

Comment: Nope. Nothing in the console.

Comment: did you tried to upgrade to latest version of ag-grid?

Comment: Yes I just upgraded ag-grid to the latest version (19) and the problem is still there.

Comment: then you should file an issue at ag-grid-aurelia github. because the comparator is not even called.

Comment: You are right, Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the issue may be with `this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite'`.  In my case, if the default `client-side` is used, then the custom comparator works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a **ServerSideDataSource**?
I don't think AG-Grid triggers the comparator when you use this.
It does however triggers the **getRows** method again.